# how to print all images of flowlayoutpanel using c#

Tags: c#, printing, flowlayoutpanel

Can anyone help me to print all 10 images which are in a flowlayoutpanel using c# (Visual Studio .NET 2005 or 2008)

I do not have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you asking about WinForms FlowLayoutPanel and you are using PictureBox-es to display images, then you can try something like this:

```
private int imagesToPrintCount;

private void PrintAllImages()
{
    imagesToPrintCount = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    dialog.Document = doc;

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        doc.Print();      
}

private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(GetNextImage(), e.MarginBounds);
    e.HasMorePages = imagesToPrintCount > 0;
}

private Image GetNextImage()
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - imagesToPrintCount];
    imagesToPrintCount--;
    return pictureBox.Image;
}
```

Keep in mind that you might need to verify control types in FlowLayoutPanel, verify images count before starting printing, scale images and some other stuff.

Comment: I am facing problem with print preview. could you help me to show print preview of all images from flowlayout control.

Comment: Create PrintPreviewDialog component and assign your PrintDocument to the Document property of preview dialog. You can use it instead PrintDialog. But keep in mind that if you will print from preview dialog, you'll need to reset imagesToPrintCount. As I rememember, you can use BeginPrint event of document.